# Coloring of a grid

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coloring

> Find the smallest positive integer $n$, such that one can color every cell of a $n \times n$ grid in red, yellow or blue with all the following conditions satisfied: 
>  1) the number of cells colored in each color is the same 
>  2) if a row contains a red cell, that row must contain a blue cell and cannot contain a yellow cell 
>  3) if a column contains a blue cell, it must contain a red cell but cannot contain a yellow cell

It's obvious that if we color one cell in a row yellow, the rest cannot be red and if we color a cell in a column yellow, the rest cannot be blue. Therefore, all yellow cells have to be in one $x \times y$ block.

Then, we have $x$ red and $n-x$ blue cells in $y$ rows, which gives us $xy$ yellow and $y(n-x)$ blue cells. We can do the same for the $x$ columns and get $xy$ yellow and $x(n-y)$ red cells.

If we now look at the block with only red and blue cells, we see that there's at least $n-y$ 
red and at least $n-x$ blue cells in it.

From that we get the following: 
$$xy=\frac{n^2}{3}$$
$$(n-y)\cdot x + n-y \leq \frac{n^2}{3}$$
$$(n-x) \cdot y+ n-x \leq \frac{n^2}{3}$$

But now I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Using what you already have,

1. Show that $ n $ is a multiple of 3.
2. Show that $(n-x) \times y  < \frac{n^2}{3} $.
3. Show that $ n > x > \frac{n}{2}, n > y > \frac{n}{2}$.
4. For $ n = 3$?, does such $x, y$ exist? If yes, can we form such a board?
5. For $ n = 6$?, does such $x, y$ exist? If yes, can we form such a board?
6. For $ n = 9$?, does such $x, y$ exist? If yes, can we form such a board?
7. For $ n = 12$?, does such $x, y$ exist? If yes, can we form such a board?